# Why is my function returning false when I am sending data from fetch function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
const haveChildren = (galactic, planet) => {
  galactic.forEach( orbit => {
    const p = planet[1]
    const o = orbit[0]
    console.log( orbit[0]===p, orbit, planet, orbit[0], p)
  })
}
```

and then I am using it inside fetch API where I am getting data from txt file

```
fetch('./data.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text)
    text = text.split('\n').map(orbit => orbit.split(')'))
    console.log(text)

    text.forEach( (element, index, array) => {
      haveChildren(array, element)
    })
  } )
```

and this is what I am getting in result: `false ['K','L'] ['J','K'] "K" "K"`

but I would expect to get `true`. Any idea?

btw. if I am testing it on any other way its work fine

even in promise: 
https://repl.it/@hejuhenryk/day6-aoc?fbclid=IwAR3AYw1tS1a-C28UzVWc_dDPb98Uibodua08xH3p04tEk9F9geQt2pqTvvI

data.txt:

```
COM)B
B)C
C)D
D)E
E)F
B)G
G)H
D)I
E)J
J)K
K)L
```

Comment: If I understand your question, `'a' !== 'a'`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-bird-cjrq7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your file uses Windows Line Endings ("\r\n" instead of "\n")?

You are splitting by `"\n"`, so that leaves `"\r"` at the end of each row, so your comparison would be `"K" === "K\r"` which is `false`.

Try something like

```
const p = planet[1].trim();
const o = orbit[0].trim();
```

And in your comparison also

```
console.log( orbit[0].trim()===p, orbit, planet, orbit[0].tirm(), p); //You can also use o instead of orbit[0] here
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never find it out by my self! 
console.log do not show that it just looks like single letter

Comment: @Heju glad I could be of assistance :) You can use `JSON.stringify(p)` or `p.length` to check if there is anything "hidden" in there